# What's the right way to delete a record in Ember Data revision 12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ember-data

I'm using revision 12 of Ember Data.

I've got a simple method on an `ArrayController` that tries to delete a single record, and is called from an action in a template:

```
deleteFact: function(fact) {
  self=this;
  window.App.confirm(Em.I18n.t('Delete fact?'), {
    yes: function() {
      fact.deleteRecord();
      fact.store.commit();
    }
  });
}
```

This always works with the first record deleted, and the list shows the record disappears. I'm using Rails, and the server processes the `DELETE` and returns a JSON empty object and `status 200`. If I delete another record any time after that first delete I always get an internal exception thrown immediately:

`Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event`deleteRecord`on <App.Fact:ember402:31> while in state rootState.deleted.saved. Called with undefined`

What's the right way to delete a record. I've searched Google and can't find any answers, and the source code and tests for ember data look like this is all that has to be done.

Template:

```
{{#each fact in content}}
  <tr>
      <td>{{fact.title}}</td>
      <td>{{fact.body}}</td>
      <td>{{#linkTo 'facts.show' fact}}View{{/linkTo}} | <a {{ action 'deleteFact' fact}} class="button small deny delete-button">Delete</a>[{{fact.id}}]({{fact.stateManager.currentState.path}})</td>
  </tr>
  {{else}}
  <tr>
    <td colspan='4'>No facts registered at present.</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Template Output:

```
Title   Facts           Actions
asdfsd  asdfsadf    View | Delete[46](rootState.loaded.saved)
asdfsd  asdfsadf    View | Delete[47](rootState.loaded.saved)
asdfsd  asdfsadf    View | Delete[48](rootState.loaded.saved)
```

Output in Console:

Clicking delete on record with Fact Id 46 logs to console from the yes function that id 46 was passed. Record disappears from list displayed by template, leaving two records with id 47, and 48. Clicking delete for record 47 shows in log that record id 46 was passed again.

Comment: Try to use `App.store.commit()` instead of `fact.store.commit()`

Comment: Same exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine.

My guess is that you keep deleting the same record. `deleteFact` seems to be called with the same `fact`.

UPDATE (trying to fix the template)

```
{{#each fact in controller}}
  <tr>
      <td>{{title}}</td>
      <td>{{body}}</td>
      <td>{{#linkTo 'facts.show'}}View{{/linkTo}} | <a {{ action 'deleteFact'}} class="button small deny delete-button">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  {{else}}
  <tr>
    <td colspan='4'>No facts registered at present.</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Your FactsController:

```
FactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'fact'
});
```

Your FactController:

```
FactController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  deleteFact: function() {
    self.get('content').deleteRecord();        
    self.get('content.transaction').commit();
  }
});
```

Comment: It's being called from an {{action}} so each fact reference should be different.

Comment: If you could provide a sample (jsfiddle) or more code so that I can reproduce the problem, it would be helpful.

Comment: @jmcd a very simple check is to `console.log(fact+"")` to check the ember guids.  This will help determine whether or not you're trying to delete the same fact.

Comment: So the fact as displayed by the template has a different id from what the action helper is passing to the method? I am deeply confused.